# MailApp error: "Message Rejected" for every single email I try to send out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a code that sends emails out through MailApp within the AppsScript. This code has worked exactly as is when I ran it under a different education account. I am now running it under a business account, and it has stopped working. Every email I send out bounces back with a "Message Rejected" error. I can't find any information as to why it would have stopped working. If I send an email out under that account manually it works fine. Any ideas? Is there something I have to authorize? Again, I've never had this issue before and I have been using Apps Script for years.

[image: An example blocked email]

Comment: Maybe inspect the email header of the email sent manually, and the email sent with Apps Script and see if there is a difference?  [Trace an email with its full headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en) It seems like the org getting the email is rejecting your email.  I'm wondering if the email header is different when it's sent from Apps Script.  But if it's being rejected because of the header, I don't know what you'd do about it.  I'm just making a wild guess.  I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I believe that a business account with a domain defaults to only sending emails within the domain.  So you may have to learn a little more about admin settings.

Comment: @Cooper, the only thing is that I feel like if I was on the wrong setting, then I wouldn't be able to send out an email manually either. I contacted Google Support and they said possibly my domain reputation was bad, but they didn't give me a solution to fix the issue.

Comment: You should definitely contact G Suite Support over this issue, you can open a case with them through [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en). You will need the trace of the email as suggested by @AlanWells, they will be able to provide a more precise answer to your issue.

Comment: @AMolina I actually did call them before making this post. They were the ones that recommended I ask Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question, I'm still not sure why Google decided that my account was a spam account, but in order to fix it I was able to use GMailApp instead of MailApp, and that worked fine. I didn't even have to change my code.